# Simple greatest common divisor proof

Tags: real-analysis

I must be missing something simple but how to show if $\gcd(ab,c^2)=1$ implies both i) $\gcd(a,c)=1$ and ii) $\gcd(b,c)=1$?

Comment: Well, what divisors do $a$ and $c$ have in common that $ab$ and $c^2$ don't?

Comment: Consider prime divisors of each argument.

Comment: The only divisor they have in common is 1?

Comment: $\gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(am,cn)\,$ for all integer $\,m,n\,$. Use that with $\,m=b, n=c,$.

Comment: Ah I can see why the first result is true but is it considered totally trivial such that it can be quoted without justification in a full proof f the problem?

Comment: Alternatively, suppose that $\gcd(a,c)=d>1$.  Then $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and a divisor of $c$.  It follows it is also a divisor of $ab$ and $c^2$, contradicting that $\gcd(ab,c^2)=1$.

Comment: No, it needs to be proven. I don't think you see it yet.  But $\gcd(a,c)$ is a factor of $a$ and of $c$.  $a$ is a factor of $ab$ so $\gcd(a,c)$ is a factor of $a$.  $c$ is a factor of $c^2$.  So $\gcd(a,c)$ is a factor of $c^2$.  So $\gcd(a,c)$ is a common factor of $ab$ and $c^2$.  But $\gcd(ab,c^2)=1$ so $ab$ and $c^2$ don't have any common factors (except 1).  So $\gcd(a,c)$ which *is* a common factor, can't be anything but $1$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $d = \gcd(a,c)$.  Then $d|a$ and $d|c$ so there are integers $k,j$ such that $a=d*k$ and $c = d*j$.

The $ab = d*(bk)$ and $c^2= d*(jc)$.  So $d$ divides both $ab$ and $c^2$.  But $\gcd(ab, c^2) =1$ so the only (positive) common factor that $ab$ and $c^2$ have in common $1$.  But they have $d$ in common.

So $d$ has to be $1$.

Same argument works to show that $\gcd(b,c)$ is a common divisor of $b$ and $c$ and thus a common divisor of $ab$ and $c^2$.

Answer (score 5):

If $r(ab)+s(c^2)=1$, then $(rb)a+(sc)c=1$ etc.

Comment: This is a correct argument, but it presupposes more knowledge than it should, judging by the level of the question. It is also less general (works in a smaller class of abstract rings) and less natural than the other one.

Answer (score 3):

By contradiction suppose $\gcd(ab,c^2)=1$ and

$$\gcd(a,c)=d>1\implies d|a \quad d|c \implies d|\gcd(ab,c^2)$$

then $\gcd(a,c)=1$.

Comment: Final statement should read $\gcd(ab,c^2)\geq d$.  It could still be greater.

Comment: yes of course you are right I was just fixing it after posing, thanks

Comment: Then should I qualify d not equals 1 so the final part contradicts?

Comment: absolutely right @dxiv

Comment: @homaniac of course you assume $d>1$ and obtain a contradiction, since gcd always exists it must be 1